# Can I pass sqlite3 'database' handles when using the TCL sqlite bindings?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

How do sqlite's tcl bindings work? Looking at an example snippet, the `sqlite3` procedure seems to open the given database and then - I guess - define a procedure `db1` which dispatches on the `eval` method?

```
sqlite3 db1 ./testdb
db1 eval {CREATE TABLE t1(a int, b text)}
```

I would have expected that I can somehow create a database object that I can pass around as a parameter in other procedures and return from a `proc connect` procedure for example.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't do just that? Can you post the code where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The `sqlite3` command creates another Tcl command (implemented in C, so formally not a procedure) whose name is given by the first argument. That command in turn encapsulates the connection handle to the database.

If you want to return the handle, just return the name (`db1` in this case). But you can also do it the other way round, and have the caller suggest what name to use. Either way works.

Note that this is a model that's used quite a few other places in object-oriented coding in Tcl, where it is common for the caller to suggest the name of the object, which is conceptually both handle and command. Or the object engine can be told to pick a name itself. (The exact preferred syntax for this has varied over the years.) Once the object is made, method calling then becomes naturally geared to parsing the first argument to the handle command.